# While loop, how do I condition for when input equals nothing?

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements

Create a program that will keep track of items for a shopping list. The program should keep asking for new items until nothing is entered (no input followed by enter key). The program should then display the full shopping list

How do I write the condition so it works?

The code I'm writing looks like this:

````
x = []

i = 0
while i != '':
    x.append(input('what u want?'))
    i = i + 1

print(x)
```
`
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find `len` of user input & check with if accordingly

```
x = []
 
while 1:
    ask= input('what u want?')
    if len(ask)>0:
        x.append(ask)

    else:
        print("Good bye")
        break
   
print(x)
```

output #

```
what u want?rice
what u want?sugar
what u want?
Good bye
['rice', 'sugar']
```

### Code correction

It is not ideal to choose hit enter to exit the loop. You need to assign keyword to make sure user really wants to exit.

```
x = []

while 1:
    ask= input('what u want?')
    if len(ask)>0 and ask !="finish":
        x.append(ask)
    else:
        print("Good bye")
        break
  
print(x)
```

With this user will have clarity when to checkout.

More interactive way:

```
x = []


while 1:
    ask= input('what u want?')
    if len(ask)>0 and ask !="finish":
        x.append(ask)

    else:
        confirmation = input('Do you really want to exit? - yes or no')
        if confirmation =="yes":
            
            print("Good bye")
            break
        else:
            print("Let's continue shopping")
            pass       

print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> only on `input()` returns an empty string.  Values such as empty containers, zero-length strings, or numerically equivalent to zero are considered false in conditional statements.

Python >= 3.8 (supports := operator):

```
items = []
while item := input('Item? '):
    items.append(item)
print(items)
```

Python < 3.8:

```
items = []
while True:
    item = input('Item? ')
    if not item: break
    items.append(item)
print(items)
```

Demo:

```
Item? one
Item? two
Item? three
Item?
['one', 'two', 'three']
```